# how to convert xlsx file to json in php and also xlsx cell contain formulas ? is possible to read the values without formula?

Tags: php, json, xlsx

I need a code for convert excel (.xlsx) file to json, but the excel file cell contain formulas, if read the data by using php, echo message will display the cell formula, how to get exact value for corresponding cells

Comment: So use a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) as a starting point, but you'll have to write some code to convert it to json in the way you want

Comment: PHPExcel can give you a representation of the XLSX file as an array. You can then use the json_encode function to convert the array to a JSON representation

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and then transform formula values from e.g. A1 to 0,0, then you can calculate the value, accessing values in the array.